# Define and execute function inside php array

Tags: php, arrays

How To define and execute a  function inside array

for example i have a array

```
    $a="a";
    $b="b";
    $c="c"; 
    $array=array(
         "a"=>$a,
         "b"=>$b,
         "c"=>function($c){
                //do something 
              return output
          }      
    )
```

here output should be

```
Array
(
    [a] => a
    [b] => b
    [c] => "new value of c"

)
```

but actually  i am getting

```
Array
(
    [a] => a
    [b] => b
    [c] => Closure Object
        (
            [parameter] => Array
                (
                    [$c] => 
                )    
        )    
)
```

NB: i can define a function outside this and call that function inside but i dont want to do that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute a function inside array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37195486/execute-a-function-inside-array)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call function in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869230/call-function-in-array-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible duplicate of Call function in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499862/can-you-store-a-function-in-a-php-array)

Comment: I ain't did anything to get these links after searching on internet, I just copy pasted your question title and saw these suggestions of google. Its that easy.....!!!!

Comment: @RahulMeshram your 3 links doesnt solved my issue

Comment: You sure, you tried all three, before posting question???? Because it seems, your accepted answer is one from above three links...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call function in array (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869230/call-function-in-array-php)

Comment: Show me exact duplicate all duplicate links here couldnt solve my issue but here i got solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [closure](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) is a function and it must be executed in order to get a response. Here's how you can execute and return a response

```
$c = 'awesome';
$array=array(
     "a"=>'test2',
     "b"=> 'test',
     "c"=> call_user_func(function() use ($c) {
            //do something 
          return $c;
      })      
);
var_dump($array);//array(3) { ["a"]=> string(5) "test2" ["b"]=> string(4) "test" ["c"]=> string(7) "awesome" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of executing the function in an array you can directly assign to some variable and call the function and pass the arguments, then you can use that assigned variable inside your array.

```
$a="a";
$b="b";
$c="c";
$d = SomeFunction($c); <-- assigning to variable
$array=array(
     "a"=>$a,
     "b"=>$b,
     "c"=> $d    
)
```